# getting datagridview error on formload : index was out of range exception

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to do programming in datagridview. In which result i want is like this: when I click on first column of datagridview (which is combobox column ) values from database should be displayed in next column(textbox column).

I am getting this exception:

> index was out of range. must be nonnegative

On this line:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
```

e.RowIndex shows -1 value.

Right now I am feeling stuck at this code. What could be the problem. Can anyone help me ?

```
     private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CellValueChanged +=
       new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
        dataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged +=
             new EventHandler(dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            // This fires the cell value changed handler below
            dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];

       // ******** e.rowindex shows -1 value.

        if (cb.Value != null)
        {

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select rate FROM Ratemaster where Packagetype = '" + comboBox1.Text +
              "' AND Tickettype ='" + ComboboxColumn.Selected + "' ", con);


             SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = dr[0].ToString();
                //dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = "hi";
            }
            else
            {
                //txtRate.Text = "0";
            }



            con.Close();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did solve this problems, with a wrapper that catches and ignores the -1 range.

```
if(e.RowIndex >= 0)
   foo();
else
   bar();
```

And:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{


if(e.RowIndex >= 0)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];

   // ******** e.rowindex shows -1 value.

    if (cb.Value != null)
    {

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select rate FROM Ratemaster where Packagetype = '" + comboBox1.Text +
          "' AND Tickettype ='" + ComboboxColumn.Selected + "' ", con);


         SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = dr[0].ToString();
            //dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = "hi";
        }
        else
        {
            //txtRate.Text = "0";
        }



        con.Close();
     }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion  friend. But I did not get what does it mean by foo() and bar(); As I am new to programming I did not understand completely. Can you elaborate your Answer ?

Comment: Hi, foo and bar and especially the concatenated word foobar is a common placeholder for any code you can imagine. I wanted to express that you should react on the if clause with your own code and ignore the else path. So you would do something like that:

Comment: @V.Vaibhav a lot of the time, programmers will use the term `foo` and `bar` or `foobar` to demonstrate an example.  The above is basically saying `if(e.RowIndex >= 0)` then do something - where `foo();` is the something (whatever you want your code to do, then replace `foo()` with it).  The same goes for the else portion of the code.

Comment: Then nothing will happen. The code does not react to anything else as I read the code.

Comment: If row x column 5's value changes, your code will go ahead and update the combo box values when those values DID NOT CHANGE...this is unnecessary if the value changed was in column 5.

Answer (score 2):

@kury’s answer is correct but appears to be missing the fact that this will fire when ANY cell value is changed. In order for this to work properly… you need to also make sure the value changed WAS actually the combo box cell. So another check is necessary to make sure the COMBO BOX value was changed:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {

  if (e.RowIndex >= 0) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) {
      DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
      //.....
      //.....
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is true. I think you can even check for the DataGridViewCellEventArgs e if there is actually a change. (At least in WPF this works)

Comment: @kurdy The event name gives away the fact that a cell value DID change. So you only need to check which cell it was.

Comment: thanks @JohnG. I want to ask you one question guys.though this solution worked to solve the error ,my code is unable to display the value in textbox column which is next to combobox column.the column remains blank. How can I fix it ?

Comment: @V.Vaibhav you are going to have to show where you are trying to set this textbox. Edit your question to show your updated code and where you are trying to set this textboxe's text.

Comment: Ok. @JohnG Thanks. I added few lines of code and its worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

instead of assigning 'CellValueChanged' event in dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(), try to assign the event from design view; using properties window.

It seems that every EditingControlShowing() event the 'CellValueChanged' event is stacking up and being called again and again, which means when EditingControlShowing() trigger first time CellValueChanged is called once, next time it will be twice and go on.

Comment: though this solution worked to solve the error ,my code is unable to display the value in textbox column which is next to combobox column.the column remains blank. How can I fix it ? can you help me ?